# Neo4J InvalidEpochException when writing to a multi-node cluster

Tags: azure, neo4j

I have a Neo4J Enterprise cluster with 6 nodes (1 master and 5 slaves) hosted in separate Linux (CentOS 6.4) VMs that I am testing an application with. The VMs are hosted in Azure. I have an object that manages connections between all 6 nodes using a simple round-robin like technique. I noticed that when writing to slave nodes, the following error message occurs several times in the messages.log file:

```
ERROR [o.n.k.h.c.m.MasterServer]: Could not finish off dead channel
org.neo4j.kernel.ha.com.master.InvalidEpochException: Invalid epoch 282880438682249,
correct epoch is 282880443056723 at 
org.neo4j.kernel.ha.com.master.MasterImpl.assertCorrectEpoch(MasterImpl.java:218) ~
[neo4j-ha-2.1.2.jar:2.1.2]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.ha.com.master.MasterImpl.finishTransaction(MasterImpl.java:363)
      ~[neo4j-ha-2.1.2.jar:2.1.2]
    at 
    org.neo4j.kernel.ha.com.master.MasterServer.finishOffChannel(MasterServer.java:70)  
    ~[neo4j-ha-2.1.2.jar:2.1.2]
    at org.neo4j.com.Server.tryToFinishOffChannel(Server.java:411) ~[neo4j-com 2.1.2.jar:2.1.2]
    at org.neo4j.com.Server$4.run(Server.java:589) [neo4j-com-2.1.2.jar:2.1.2]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [na:1.7.0_60]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [na:1.7.0_60]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_60]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_60]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_60]
```

I am at a loss. Why does this error occur? When this error occurs, the write fails. I have the servers synchronizing their time via NTP. The application writing to Neo4J is a .Net application using the Neo4JClient library. Thank you for any guidance you can provide.

Amir.

Answer (score 0):

The `InvalidEpochException` might occur when a master happen while a slave is in progress of committing a transaction. The main reason for unexpected master switches are lengthy GC pauses, longer than cluster timeout settings.

So you need to analyze GC behaviour and optimize them or tweak your cluster timeout settings.

Comment: Thank you, Stefan. What is an appropriate cluster timeout setting and which settings should be specifically targeted?

Comment: Amir, first check if you're suffering from GC issues. Adopting timeouts has some drawbacks as well. E.g. enable gc logging in `neo4j-wrapper.conf`.